# Vuejs copy dynamic components methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am trying to make a visual representation of a component library. I am using dynamic `<component>`s to render each component. However, as I am populating the component with its slots, I am running into issues due to parent methods missing.

I want the components to be usable (demo) therefore I need to compensate for `this.$parent` not working.

```
<template>
  <component v-bind:is="'s-' + comp.name" v-bind="props" ref="comp">  <!-- this is the corrent parent-->
    <div v-if="comp.slots">
      <div
        v-for="(slot, i) in comp.slots"
        v-bind:key="i"
        v-bind:slot="slot.name"
      >
        <div v-if="slot.type == 'component'">                         <!-- childs parent -->
          <de-mo v-bind:comp="slot" />                                <!-- this is the child calling a method on the parent -->
        </div>
        <div v-html="slot.value" v-else></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'deMo',
  computed: {
    props() {
      if (this.comp.props) {
        return this.comp.props.reduce((a, r) => {
          a[r.name] = r.value
          return a
        }, {})
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    comp: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: this.$ref.comp.methods,                               //<-- this is an error
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.$ref.comp.methods)
  }
},

</script>

<style></style>
```

1) Is there a way to copy the methods from the parent into this "demo" component via the `ref` attr
2) Alternatively, is there a better method to produce the same results?

Thanks

Comment: The component library should use Inject provide, it's the recommended way, not direct tree parenting which doesn't work if the child is within an intermediate element

Answer (score 1):

you can try to spread parent methods in a beforeCreate lifecycle as at this point your parent will be created and your component is going to register its all methods,

```
beforeCreate() {
    this.$options.methods = { ...this.$parent.$options.methods };
  },
```

however you can not access any refs in this as refs are only registered after mount of the component.

Note: Any library should use provide and inject to communicate with their component instead of referencing the parent component directly.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use an **Event bus** to communicate between components that aren't directly related to each other. Also, this is the **recommended** way of communication from child to parent in Vue.

**bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

**demo.vue** // child component that wants to call a method in the parent

```
import Bus from './bus.js'
export default {
 mounted () {
  // [1] child component will emit an event in the bus when it want to call a method of parent 
  Bus.$emit('invoke-parent-fn', 'param')
 }
}
```

**parent.vue** // parent component where you want to render other components dynamically

```
import Bus from './bus.js'
export default {
 methods: {
  fn (param) {
   console.log('// do something ' + param)
  }
 },
 mounted () {
  // [2] parent will be listening to the bus event, when child will emit an event, the handler passed in to the listener will be invoked
  // [3] invoke the required method in the handler
  Bus.$on('invoke-parent-fn', param => this.fn(param))
 }
}
```